# Cannot Connect UILabel to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

New to Swift and Xcode here.

So in my Main.storyboard I have some buttons and a label. I've been able to connect the buttons to my ViewController:

```
@IBAction func clickRock(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
```

But now for the UILabel, I click and drag to the ViewController but nothing happens.

I tried creating an IBOutlet in the code and connecting in the other way but that didn't work either:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: have you added the class name to your storyboard?

Comment: Yep, hence why the buttons work.

Comment: * Correction, not all the scene's were connected to the ViewController. This solved this.

Answer (score 1):

You would be surprised by how many problems are fixed by force quitting Xcode and reopening your project.